# Как обновить значение переменной?

Tags: javascript

Я написал такой скрипт

```
<script>
var c = 0;
function img(){
var t = setTimeout('img()',1000);
c++;
document.write(c);
}
</script>
```

У меня возникла такая проблема, данный скрипт выводит значения по такой системе: 
123456789... и так дальше. А мне бы хотелось, чтоб оно постоянно меня значение. 1 потом обновилось 2 обновилось 3 и так дальше. чтоб каждое чилсло выводилось индивидуально, а не все подряд, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Comment: Заведите себе визуальный элемент на страничке, и обновляйте значение в нём, делов-то.

Comment: делом в том, что я только вчера вечером начал изучать яваскрипт. Поэтому пока мало об нем знаю! И не нужно меня минусить!

Comment: Минусатор не я, но ваш вопрос по сути тривиален, и лучшим ответом было бы отослать вас к учебнику. Тем, кто разбирается в html/js, неинтересно в стопицотый раз объяснять основы.

Comment: Ну по моему, сайт этот и для того создан, для помощи, или я не прав?

Comment: где-то тут был вопрос, про [сравнение чисел](http://hashcode.ru/questions/183519/)...

>Ну по моему, сайт этот и для того создан, для помощи, или я не прав?

помощь понятие растяжимое, возможно большей помощью будет именно отослать вас читать книги, чем показывать готовое решение

>делом в том, что я только вчера вечером начал изучать яваскрипт

отличное оправдание

Comment: @oOKomarOo: вы удивитесь, но я на этом сайте не получаю зарплату. Поэтому я отвечаю только на те вопросы, которые мне интересны. Если мне кажется, что ответ на вопрос в любом учебнике на первой странице, мне не так уж и интересно на него отвечать. Я с удовольствием помогаю решить проблемы, которые мне самому кажутся интересными и нетривиальными, из которых я и сам что-то почерпну.

Comment: -__- Я серьезно вчера начал учить, лол.

Comment: @VladD, полностью солидарен, хотя если будет приведено оригинальное красивое решение, возможно я восприниму как вызов, и сделаю ещё оригинальнее и/или красивее

Comment: @Spectre: да, так часто бывает: вопрос вроде тривиальный, но кто-то опубликует интересное решение, и тогда начинается обсуждение.

Comment: Ох, ну да, я забыл здесь же сидят "профи" которые новичкам ничего не могут подсказать, ибо считают себя большими верстальщиками. И помогать нубам не царское дело..

Comment: @oOKomarOo, о да, 2 минуса, какой достойный поступок

>Ох, ну да, я забыл здесь же сидят "профи" которые новичкам ничего не могут подсказать

тов. @VladD в первом же комменте подсказал вам, но видимо вас это не устроило

Comment: ох не удержался. Один из минусов поставил я. За "Ох, ну да, я забыл здесь же сидят "профи" которые новичкам ничего не могут подсказать, ибо считают себя большими верстальщиками. И помогать нубам не царское дело..". 

1. держите себя в руках. Здесь никто Вам ничем не обязан. 
2. в первом комментарии есть ответ.
3. в каждой книге по js и в поиске есть ответ на Ваш вопрос.
4. то что Вы "вчера начал учить" - это, Вы, молодец. Если Вы будите продолжать то поймете, что значит первый комментарий к вашему вопросу и решите Вашу проблему самостоятельно(почти).

Comment: >здесь же сидят "профи" которые новичкам ничего не могут подсказать, ибо считают себя большими верстальщиками. И помогать нубам не царское дело

чесслово, я от этих слов плакал горькими слезами)))) 
Школьник, ты даже не отличаешь программистов от верстальщиков)))) 
Насчет того, что "не царское дело" - это ты верно подметил - на каждого нуба никакой  помогалки не хватит. А судя по тебе - помогать таким и вовсе бесполезно. Все равно потом вместо того, чтоб прочесть какую-нибудь хорошую книгу, будешь задавать вопросы типа "а как мне сложить два числа и вывести ответ?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

document.write добавляет к имеющемуся документу содержимое.

В вашем случае лучше ввести в документ элемент, содержимому которого присваивать значение переменной.

```
<script>
var c = 0;
function img(){
    var t = setTimeout('img()',1000);
    c++;
    document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = c;
}
</script>
```

А где-то внутри body добавить элемент с id="c", например div:

```
<div id="c"/>
```

Comment: И какую пользу это принесёт? Вам так нужны баллы?

Comment: @VladD, конечно принесёт.

В любом случае не думаю, что стоит минусовать Пётра Таранова за то, что он помог топикстартеру.

Comment: @LightShock: Какую пользу? Чему он научится? Ctrl-C -- Ctrl-V? Не читать книги? Не пользоваться гуглом? Рассчитывать не на свои знания, а на помощь других?

Comment: >Чему он научится?

@VladD, хамить, но всё равно получать помощь

Comment: @VladD
1. Польза в том, что человек решит интересующую его задачу.
2. Баллы не интересуют.
Я удовлетворил ваше любопытство?

Comment: По поводу (2) поверю, а вот по поводу (1) у меня серьёзные сомнения. Если человек спрашивает такое, он очевидно совершенно не разбирается в вопросе, и вовсе не хочет разобраться. Поэтому для решения любой сколько-нибудь неучебной задачи ему таких вот вопросов придётся задать не меньше сотни, и так с каждой следующей задачей. Короче, не взлетит.

Answer (score 0):

НУ тут все просто если у Вас документе больше ничего нет то чистите его к черту и выводите.
Ну например так

```
var c = 0;
function img(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML="";
    document.write(c);
    var t = setTimeout(img,1000);
    c++;
}

img();
```

[Вот как работает](http://jsfiddle.net/CkEh8/)